# Insert Muti Record From Android To Php?

Tags: php, mysql

When Send Data With Json From Android(AS) to Server (php+mysql) Must 1 Record Insert But Multi Record Selected Why?

[image: no image description]

my php code is:

```
include ('connect.php');




  $jsondata = file_get_contents('php://input' );

   if($jsondata==""){
echo "forbiden";
}
else{
    $data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

    //get the employee details
    $user = $data['name'];
    $namayandegi = $data['code_namayandegi'];
    $code = $data['kala_code'];
    $name = $data['kala_name'];
    $tedad= $data['kala_tedad'];
    $cost= $data['kala_cost'];
    $date= $data['date'];
    $confirm= $data['confirm'];
    $email=$data['email'];



$sql="INSERT INTO `final_factor`(`id`, `name`, `code_namayandegi`, `kala_code`, `kala_name`, `kala_tedad`, `kala_mablagh`, `date`, `confirm`,`email`)
 VALUES ('','$user','$namayandegi','$code','$name','$tedad','$cost','$date','$confirm','$email')";


    if(mysql_query($sql,$con))
    {
       echo "1";
}  
  }
```

Comment: What is a "tow record"? I appreciate English may not be your first language but you could at least use a spell checker.

Comment: Thank You My Friend...Please See Image And Help Me.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you don't need to insert the id in you query and it's supposed to be AI. 
So your query would be something like this

```
    $sql="INSERT INTO `final_factor`( `name`, `code_namayandegi`, `kala_code`, `kala_name`, `kala_tedad`, `kala_mablagh`, `date`, `confirm`,`email`)
 VALUES ('$user','$namayandegi','$code','$name','$tedad','$cost','$date','$confirm','$email')";
```

Second: The only reason why there are duplicate rows is that your code is repeating itself somewhere and for some reason. it could be multiple page loads or something like this. It's not possible to tell it because the code you provided has no errors so maybe it's not all the code. It would be great if you provide all your code. If you don't want look after what I told. Somewhere your code is called twice. Look after that.